# Dividir una función en otras dos en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Quiero dividir la función `traducir` en dos funciones:

- `validar`: se encarga de validar los datos ingresados.
- `traducir`: se encarga exclusivamente de pasar de decimal a binario.

Quizás mi idea se debe a falta de experiencia, pero tengo la idea de que cuanto más "chicas" sean las tareas que cumple una función, más óptimo es el código (de leer).

Logré hacer las dos cosas en una sola función, pero no en dos funciones separadas:

```
<div class="container">
        <input type="text" name="inp-bin" id="inp-bin" class="container__inp" placeholder="Ingrese un número binario"></input>
        <input type="text" name="inp-dec" id="inp-dec" class="container__inp" readonly></input>
        <button id="btnTraslate" class="container__btn">Traducir a decimal</button>
    </div>

function traducir() {
    let binario = document.getElementById('inp-bin').value;
    if (binario === '') {
        document.getElementById('inp-dec').value = '';
        return alert('[Error] Ingrese números');
    }

    let cadenaBinaria = binario.split('');
    for (let num of cadenaBinaria) {
        if (num != '0' && num != '1') {
            document.getElementById('inp-bin').value = '';
            document.getElementById('inp-dec').value = '';
            return alert('[Error] Ingrese sólo ceros y unos');
        }
    }
    
    let decimal = parseInt(binario, 2);
    document.getElementById('inp-dec').value = decimal;
}

let btnTraslate = document.getElementById('btnTraslate');
btnTraslate.addEventListener('click', () => {
    traducir();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quizá lo que deseas es aislar completamente la funcionalidad de la comprobación de los campos de la de devolución de un valor como hago a continuación:

```js
function validar() {
    const binario = document.getElementById('inp-bin').value;
    if (binario === '') {
        document.getElementById('inp-dec').value = '';
        alert('[Error] Ingrese números');
        return;
    }
    const decimal = traducir(binario);
    /* Si dio error de conversión mostramos el error */
    if (decimal === false) {
        document.getElementById('inp-bin').value = '';
        document.getElementById('inp-dec').value = '';
        return alert('[Error] Ingrese sólo ceros y unos');
    }
    document.getElementById('inp-dec').value = decimal;
}

/* Paramos como parámetro la cadena a convertir. Devuelve false si no son 1s y 0s */
function traducir(cadena) {
    let cadenaBinaria = cadena.split('');
    for (let num of cadenaBinaria) {
        if (num != '0' && num != '1') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return parseInt(cadena, 2);
}

let btnTraslate = document.getElementById('btnTraslate');
btnTraslate.addEventListener('click', validar);
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" name="inp-bin" id="inp-bin" class="container__inp" placeholder="Ingrese un número binario" />
    <input type="text" name="inp-dec" id="inp-dec" class="container__inp" readonly />
    <button id="btnTraslate" class="container__btn">Traducir a decimal</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Me he permitido la libertad de cambiar el nombre de tu función a `validar`, que es lo que pide el OP.

Answer (score 5):

Personalmente, yo no reinventaría la rueda.

Si `parseInt()` ofrece la funcionalidad de convertir un número a base 2, no crearía una función para encapsular dicha funcionalidad. En su lugar detectaría cuándo la conversión ha sido errónea y devuelve un `NaN` (*Not a Number*). Esto ocurre, por ejemplo, al pasar como parámetro un valor que o no es un número o no tiene solo `1`s y `0`s.

Además, HTML5 te ofrece la posibilidad de definir el formato que debe tener un campo mediante varios métodos. Yo te voy a mostrar un ejemplo usando [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern):

```
<input type="text" name="inp-bin" id="inp_bin" class="container__inp"
    pattern="[01]+" required="required" title="Introduzca solo unos y ceros"
    placeholder="Ingrese un número binario" />
```

El patrón `[01]+` significa: tantos ceros y unos como se deseen, pero al menos uno. Si en vez de un `+` ponemos un `*` entonces se incluiría la ausencia, ningún dígito.

Como el control del formulario se saltaría el formulario vacío, es necesario agregar el atributo [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required), que impide enviar el formulario con el campo sin rellenar.

Por último, para que la comprobación funcione también cuando pulses <kbd>ENTER</kbd> he encapsulado los campos del formulario en un formulario y realizo la comprobación en el evento de envío, que se produce al pulsar en el botón `submit` como al pulsar <kbd>ENTER</kbd> en el campo del formulario.

A continuación te muestro cómo podrías hacerlo:

```js
function validar(evento) {
    /* Evitamos el envío del formulario */
    evento.preventDefault();
    /* La conversión debería funcionar, el navegador comprobó la validez */
    inp_dec.value = parseInt(inp_bin.value, 2);
}

/* Realizamos la conversión en el evento de envío del formulario */
formulario.addEventListener('submit', validar);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form id="formulario">
    <input type="text" name="inp-bin" id="inp_bin" class="container__inp"
        pattern="[01]+" required="required" title="Introduzca solo unos y ceros"
        placeholder="Ingrese un número binario" />
    <input type="text" name="inp-dec" id="inp_dec" class="container__inp" readonly />
    <button type="submit" id="btnTraslate" class="container__btn">Traducir a decimal</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

PD: Además, te recomiendo que los identificadores no contengan un guión (`-`) para poder usar el identificador como variable autogenerada en el ámbito global. Te ahorrarás usar `getElementById()` innecesarios.

PD2: Código copiado a respuesta desde la respuesta de [@franmost](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/41813/franmost).

PD3: Si deseas mantener un control del patrón introducido en el formulario porque podrían usar un navegador que no sea compatible con HTML5 (algo casi imposible a día de hoy, pero podrías requerirlo) entonces el código podría ser:

```js
function validar(evento) {
    /* Evitamos el envío del formulario */
    evento.preventDefault();
    const decimal = parseInt(inp_bin.value, 2);
    /* Comprobamos que se respete el patrón y la conversión */
    if (
        inp_bin.value.match(/^[01]+$/) === null
        || isNaN(decimal)
    ) {
        inp_bin.value = inp_dec.value = '';
        alert('[Error] Introduzca solo unos y ceros');
    } else {
        inp_dec.value = decimal;
    }
}

/* Realizamos la conversión en el evento de envío del formulario */
formulario.addEventListener('submit', validar);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form id="formulario">
    <input type="text" name="inp-bin" id="inp_bin" class="container__inp"
        pattern="[01]+" required="required" title="Introduzca solo unos y ceros"
        placeholder="Ingrese un número binario" />
    <input type="text" name="inp-dec" id="inp_dec" class="container__inp" readonly />
    <button type="submit" id="btnTraslate" class="container__btn">Traducir a decimal</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Buenos días Oscar, gracias por tus correcciones y tu respuesta. Encontré que tu solución tiene el inconveniente de que si por ejemplo ingreso 0152452, traduce el 01 (correctamente lo traduce a 1) pero no debería hacer eso ya que por más que empiece con los números requeridos, el conjunto no cumple con los requisitos. Muchas gracias de todas formas, fue de gran ayuda tu aporte.

Comment: No hay problema, entonces se puede mejorar la comprobación con una expresión regular. Se puede hacer tanto a nivel del campo del formulario, como a nivel de código Javascript.

Comment: Hecha la modificación, en la que la comprobación la hace HTML5 y no Javascript. Aunque he mantenido al final de la respuesta cómo se comprobaría por patrón en caso de que quieras hacerlo.

Comment: Era un ejercicio lo que pasa, la idea es practicar JavaScript, pero muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Perfecto, espero que mi respuesta, al menos, te ayudara a conocer mejor el funcionamiento de `parseInt()` e `isNaN()` 

Answer (score 1):

Creo que la respuesta de [@OscarGarcia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/477488/54039) es la más acertada, porque simplifica el proceso en una sola función con pocas líneas y proporciona excelentes argumentos de porqué hacerlo así.

Esta respuesta es solo para plantear otras posibilidades al buscar que una cadena cumpla con formato o solo caracteres específicos mediante una expresión regular en vez de un ciclo. Además, si quieres que las funciones sean reutilizables, entonces deben recibir el valor como parámetro.

```js
// Validar
function validar(str) {
    // Expresión regular para que solo pueda contener ceros y unos
    // ^         Analizar desde el inicio de la cadena
    // ([0-1])   Buscar solo caracteres cero y uno
    // +         Debe contener uno o más caracteres del grupo anterior
    // $         Analizar hasta el final de la cadena
    return /^([0-1])+$/g.test(str);
}

// Traducir
function traducir(str) {
    return parseInt(str, 2);
}

// Lógica en una función aparte
function btnClick(e) {
    // Si el botón pertenece a un formulario y no tiene tipo
    // por defecto será submit y hay que cancelar su comportamiento
    e.preventDefault();
    let num = document.getElementById('inp-bin').value;
    if(validar(num)) {
        document.getElementById('inp-dec').value = traducir(num);
    } else {
        console.log('Ingresa solo ceros y unos');
    }
}

// Escuchar clics en botón
document.getElementById('btnTraslate').addEventListener('click', btnClick);
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" name="inp-bin" id="inp-bin" class="container__inp" placeholder="Ingrese un número binario">
    <input type="text" name="inp-dec" id="inp-dec" class="container__inp" readonly>
    <button id="btnTraslate" class="container__btn">Traducir a decimal</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez con algo como esto:

```
function validar(value) {
    return value === ''
}

function traducir() {
    let binario = document.getElementById('inp-bin').value;
    if (validar(binario)) {
        //esto tal vez sea otra funcion ya que restablece valores y alerta al usuario
        document.getElementById('inp-dec').value = '';
        return alert('[Error] Ingrese números');
    }

    let cadenaBinaria = binario.split('');
    for (let num of cadenaBinaria) {
        if (num != '0' && num != '1') {
            document.getElementById('inp-bin').value = '';
            document.getElementById('inp-dec').value = '';
            return alert('[Error] Ingrese sólo ceros y unos');
        }
    }
    
    let decimal = parseInt(binario, 2);
    document.getElementById('inp-dec').value = decimal;
}
```

Espero que te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: Lo que desea el OP no es solo dividir una función en dos, si no aislar la funcionalidad de cada una y que `traducir()` solo traduzca y se pueda reutilizar.